# Dodge 350 1985 5,9L V8

Tags: ignition, dodge, ram, distributor

Hi my dodge turn off while driving and doesn’t start any more. Everything worked normal, I think in the ignition distributor is the charcoal pencil used.

Sorry for my bad English I am from Germany

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I'm not sure what you mean by "charcoal pencil" ... are you talking about the center button inside the rotor cap? The part which connects to the coil? If so, have you done any visual inspection of the cap? I'm not quite sure how you'd come to the conclusion without looking. Also, I'm not quite sure what your question is. If you'd please edit the body of your post and ensure the question is specified, it'll sure go a long way to helping us to help you :o)

Comment: If you think something is broken in the distributor, can you add a photo of it?